# Using Jackson and Lombok, is there way to map json fields to static variables

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

I have to read the JSON file and inject environment property as a static variable.
Here is the JSON

```
{
 "env":"staging",
 "index": "test",
 "indval": "testVal"
 
}
```

I need to map only **env** field as static string variable in my Class using **Jackson and Lombok**

```
@Data
public class PubConf {

   public static String env;
   private String index;
   private String indval;

}
```

I always getting below error for the above class

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "env"
```

**Appreciate your thoughts for resolving this**

Comment: `Static` field doesn't belong to class instance that's why.

Comment: Why would you need two variables to be linked to an instance but one variable to be static? Seems like there's a design issue with what you are trying to do.

Comment: it's a strange design, but why don't you just write nonstatic getter/setter for env?

Comment: @JasperKetelaar Here I store the system properties in the JSON file. And I need to use only environment-related fields as static variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Data
public class PubConf {

   private String env;
   private String index;
   private String indval;
 
    @JsonIgnore
    public static String statEnv;

    public void setEnv(String env) {
        PubConf.statEnv= env;
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field

Answer (score 0):

use create a instance method and use @JsonSetter on it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).